# Cannot include standard libraries in C++ file

Tags: c++, macos, clang

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    std::cout << "Hello World\n";
    return 0;
}
```

command 1 (works)

```
clang hello.cc -o hello -lc++
```

command 2 (don't works)

```
/path/to/custom/clang hello.cc -o hello -lc++

main.cc:2:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include <iostream>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

Why I can't compile with `command 2` ?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're trying to compile C++ with a C compiler. Try running `clang++` instead.

```
clang++ hello.cc -o hello
```

Without running clang as a C++ compiler it won't have the C++ standard library headers available for you to include. Using `clang++` the C++ standard library headers are available and the C++ standard library is linked for you automatically.

Comment: You are right. I've tried with a c program and it works. I discovered that the [custom clang](https://github.com/obfuscator-llvm/obfuscator/tree/clang-425.0.24) I'm using does not contains a clang++.

Answer (score 1):

That is a known Ubuntu issue.  Their `clang` just isn't set up right. I complained about it [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/383029/clang-version-3-3-lacks-headers) -- and this remained unfixed for years.

But the *good news* is that it now works with the most recent 16.10 release.

*Edit:* Based on your updated question I would say that "custom clang" does not know about its include files.

Comment: I'm on macOS. maybe it's the same issue.
 Is there a workaround to fix that ?

Comment: I used to fiddle with -I switches but it gets messier because the two possible implementations of the C++ standard library.   I don't have an OS X box, but friends do, and `clang` and `clang++` clearly work for them. Sometimes, though, there is also a need for `g++` (to get OpenMP, say). My  pal @coatless as a number of posts [on his blog](http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/).